# C++ how to avoid ambiguous move constructors

Tags: c++11, constructor, move-semantics

I have a class with a couple of fields, `assignment c-tor` and `move c-tor`:

```
class A{
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    int k;


public:

    A(std::vector<int> &&numbers, const int k):
        numbers(numbers), // fast
        k(k)
    {
        // logic
    }

    A(const std::vector<int> &numbers, const int k):
        A(std::move(std::vector<int>(numbers)), k) // copy-and-move vector
    {
        // empty
    }
};
```

I want to keep `logic` in one `c-tor` and call it from others.
Also, I want to support fast `move-semantics`. And I have to explicitly `copy-and-move` arguments in the `assignment c-tor`.

**Is there any way to avoid such nested construction and keep all advantages I've listed above?**

Comment: You forgot to `std::move` so your constructor with the `&&` actually does a copy. You don't have to explicitly copy and move in the assignment variant, not sure why you're doing that.

Comment: @MooingDuck Why? `vector` has a `move c-tor` which accepts `std::vector<T> &&` as argument. Why should I move already moved value?

Comment: @LibertyPaul It has a name, so it's an lvalue: you need std::move to promote it back to an rvalue in the call to `std::vector<int>()`

Answer (score 4):

You could delegate one constructor to the other:

```
struct A
{
    A(const std::vector<int> & v) : A(std::vector<int>(v)) {}

    A(std::vector<int> && v)
    : v_(std::move(v))
    {
        // logic
    }

    // ...
};
```

The moving constructor is now as fast as it can be, and the copying constructor costs one more move than if you spell both constructors out. If you're willing to pay an extra move, though, you might as well just have a single constructor:

```
struct A
{
    A(std::vector<int> v)
    : v_(std::move(v))
    {
        // logic
    }
};
```

The alternative is to put the common code into a function and call that from both constructors.

Comment: Does `std::vector<int>(v)` produces `std::vector<int> &&`? And if yes why should I move it again? Doesn't `vector constructor` accept `std::vector<int> &&` which we have received as an argument?

Comment: @LibertyPaul: Anything with a name is an lvalue. Just because the parameter requires the supplied value be an rvalue doesn't mean it is an rvalue too.

Comment: @kfsone: No: `std::move` is a function, and the result of the function call is an *expression*. Expressions are never references. The correct way to say it is that `std::move` turns any value into an rvalue.