# std::vector push_back rvalue does not compile

Tags: c++

I am making `MultiVector` class for Entity Component System. It is used for storing objects of different types for iterating over them efficiently.
I use vectors of bytes as raw storage and `reinterpret_cast` it to whichever type I need. Basic functionality (`push_back` by const reference and `pop_back`) seems to work.
However, when I try to implement move semantics for `push_back` (commented lines), clang gives me incomprehensible 186 lines error message, something about 'allocate is declared as pointer to a reference type'. As I understand, vector tries to `push_back` reference to `T`, which it cannot do because it must own contained objects.
How am I supposed to do it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int g_class_id { 0 };
template <class T>
const int get_class_id()
{
    static const int id { g_class_id++ };
    return id;
}

class MultiVector {
public:
    MultiVector() : m_vectors(g_class_id + 1) {}

    template <typename T>
    vector<T>& vector_ref() {
        const int T_id { get_class_id<T>() };
        if (T_id >= m_vectors.size()) {
            m_vectors.resize(T_id + 1);
        }
        vector<T>& vector_T { *reinterpret_cast<vector<T>*>(&m_vectors[T_id]) };
        return vector_T;
    }

    template<typename T>
    void push_back(const T& value) {
        vector_ref<T>().push_back(value);
    }

    // Move semantics, take rvalue reference
    template<typename T>
    void push_back(T&& value) {
        vector_ref<T>().push_back(std::move(value));
    }

    template <typename T>
    void pop_back() {
        vector_ref<T>().pop_back();
    }

private:
    vector<vector<byte>> m_vectors;
};

template<typename T>
void show(const vector<T>& vct)
{
    for (const auto& item : vct) cout << item << ' ';
    cout << '\n';
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    string hello = "hello";
    string world = "world";
    MultiVector mv;
    mv.push_back(10);
    mv.push_back(20);
    mv.push_back(2.7);
    mv.push_back(3.14);
    mv.push_back(hello);
    mv.push_back(world);
    show(mv.vector_ref<int>());
    show(mv.vector_ref<double>());
    show(mv.vector_ref<string>());
    mv.vector_ref<int>().pop_back();
    show(mv.vector_ref<int>());
    return 0;
}
```

Tried to replace rvalue reference `T&&` to just value `T`, does not compile too because call to `push_back` becomes ambiguous.

**Edit:** In function with `T&& value` argument `vector_ref<T>()` cannot even push default value to rewrite it via placement `new` operator, because type of vector deduced as `vector<T&>`. How do I make compiler deduce type of vector as `vector<T>`?

**Edit 2:** @kaba's idea with `std::remove_reference` works but it works too well :) Now if I pass lvalue reference, `push_back` moves from it unless it is reference to `const` object. It can be solved by explicitly instantiating template instead of letting compiler deduce type, which I guess will work but still leaves me unsatisfied and confused. I don't understand why compiler can distinguish `const T&` and `T&&` from value in `std::vector` but not in my case.

Second version of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

uint32_t g_class_id { 0 };
template <class T>
uint32_t get_class_id()
{
    static const uint32_t id { g_class_id++ };
    return id;
}

class MultiVector {
public:
    MultiVector() = default;

    template <typename T>
    vector<T>& vector_ref() {
        const uint32_t T_id { get_class_id<T>() };
        if (T_id >= m_vectors.size()) {
            m_vectors.resize(T_id + 1);
            m_vectors[T_id].reserve(16 * sizeof(T)); // avoid reallocations for tests
        }
        vector<T>& vector_T { *reinterpret_cast<vector<T>*>(&m_vectors[T_id]) };
        return vector_T;
    }

    template<typename T>
    void push_back(const T& value) {
        vector_ref<T>().push_back(value);
    }

    // Move semantics, take rvalue reference
    template<typename T>
    void push_back(T&& value) {
        vector_ref<typename std::remove_reference<T&&>::type>().push_back(std::move(value));
    }

    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    void emplace_back(Args&&... args) {
        vector_ref<T>().emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template <typename T>
    void pop_back() {
        vector_ref<T>().pop_back();
    }

private:
    vector<vector<byte>> m_vectors;
};

template<typename T>
void show(const vector<T>& vct)
{
    for (const auto& item : vct) cout << item << ' ';
    cout << '\n';
}

struct A {
    int x{};
    A()                        { cout << "default ctor\n"; }
    explicit A(int v) : x{v}   { cout << "value ctor with " << x << '\n'; }
    A(const A& rhs) : x{rhs.x} { cout << "copy  ctor with " << x << '\n'; }
    A(A&& rhs) : x{rhs.x}      { rhs.x = 0; cout << "move  ctor with " << x << '\n'; }
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const A& a) {
    os << '(' << a.x << ')'; return os;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    MultiVector mv;
    A a{1};
    const A ca{2};
    cout << "-- deduce type from call --\n";
    mv.push_back(a);
    mv.push_back(ca);
    mv.push_back(A{3});
    mv.emplace_back<A>(4);
    show(mv.vector_ref<A>());
    cout << "a:  " << a << '\n';
    cout << "ca: " << ca << '\n';
    while (not mv.vector_ref<A>().empty()) mv.vector_ref<A>().pop_back();
    cout << "-- explicitly name type --\n";
    a.x = 1;
    mv.push_back<A>(a);
    mv.push_back<A>(ca);
    mv.push_back<A>(A{3});
    mv.emplace_back<A>(4);
    show(mv.vector_ref<A>());
    cout << "a:  " << a << '\n';
    cout << "ca: " << ca << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
value ctor with 1
value ctor with 2
-- deduce type from call --
move  ctor with 1
copy  ctor with 2
value ctor with 3
move  ctor with 3
value ctor with 4
(1) (2) (3) (4) 
a:  (0)
ca: (2)
-- explicitly name type --
copy  ctor with 1
copy  ctor with 2
value ctor with 3
move  ctor with 3
value ctor with 4
(1) (2) (3) (4) 
a:  (1)
ca: (2)
```

Comment: A side note: `T&&` is this context is not really an R-value refrence, but rather a forwarding reference. See: [When is a reference a forwarding reference, and when is it an rvalue reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45996187/when-is-a-reference-a-forwarding-reference-and-when-is-it-an-rvalue-reference).

Comment: I'm not sure how the compiler is supposed to know if you want to copy or move. You may need to rename one of the functions to e.g. push_back_move()

Comment: @SvenNilsson just one overload with perfect forwarding `push_back(std::forward<T>(v))` will do

Comment: Okay, yeah more on it here it seems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401588/c-how-to-avoid-ambiguous-move-constructors

Comment: Not really an answer to the R-value ref question, but if you remove the `push_back` `T&&` overload altogether it will work: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ErcjfE81n).

Comment: You should use std::vector <std::any> instead.

Comment: @Eugene Whole point of this class is optimization for ECS. Store by type so type is implicit and functions can be called over contiguous range of elements. With `std::any` I would have to check for value, store type and cast to type.

Comment: The answer to your edit question should be simple: just use the type-trait `remove_reference`: `vector_ref<std::remove_reference<T>::type>()`. c.f. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference